# Does Terraform intend to ignore changes if arguments are omitted?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Let's say I created an app service using azurerm_app_service with the bare minimum arguments. If I later go into Azure Portal and start creating IP restrictions and later run Terraform apply, it seems that Terraform doesn't detect drift and try to undo all of the IP restrictions. Is that working as intended? Is there Terraform documentation that says this is intended?

This behavior works in our favor, because it tells us that Terraform is OK with configuration drift so long as the argument or argument object is not defined in the configuration script. We intend to let Azure Portal users what is OK and not OK to modify in the portal without worrying about Terraform resetting it all.

Update: Accepted answer below and also received more feedback from Hashicorp's forum, https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-not-detecting-drift-on-resources-intended-or-not/17547/4?u=terraform-man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to depend on how the resource is implemented, the schema and what is changing.  Typically with azurerm provider it should [compute](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/378d504b5bd542fd6955363595b616276a7165ff/azurerm/internal/services/web/app_service.go#L805) those changes even if they are optional.  I would double check your terraform config and the portal resource you are modify are the same.  You might need to run a refresh.  In other words it is very common for changes in the portal to show up as drift when you run terraform.

Comment: I'm looking at the schema and I see that the computed attribute is `true`. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/master/azurerm/internal/services/web/app_service.go#L859
Doesn't a refresh occur automatically when `terraform apply` is ran?

Comment: Confirmed that refresh is automatically ran during apply and plan. 
https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/detecting-and-managing-drift-with-terraform
"All plan and apply commands run refresh first, prior to any other work."

Comment: I see where you get your information about how the schema dictates this, https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/best-practices/detecting-drift.html but in the case of the azurerm_app_service schema, it doesn't seem to be doing whats expected. What can you make out of this based on the schema I linked?

Comment: I got some feedback from the Hashicorp forums and it aligns with your response that these drift changes can only be detected based on how the provider implemented the resource, as you said.
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-not-detecting-drift-on-resources-intended-or-not/17547/4?u=terraform-man

Comment: I'll accept it as an answer, although if you have additional time to look over why the schema for the ip_restriction doesn't tell terraform there's been drift, that would be great. I want to learn how to identify the resources schema will not detect drift, like in my case.

Comment: Post your code and the version of terraform and the azurerm provider.  It could be a bug too. - Might be worth posting it on github if you think there is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is called Desired State Vs Current State.
If you create any resource using terraform and manually modify it, Terraform reverts it after next apply.
Before Terraform Apply command, it fetches the current state into the statefile and then compares the current state vs desired state.
If there is any manual change, it will make necessary changes to make it as Desired state.

Comment: In case you missed it, I noticed if I create a azurerm_app_service without an ip_restriction block in Terraform, and then manually add IP restrictions in Azure Portal, and run terraform apply later...these changes are NOT reverted. This seems to be common across other resources as well. Just as long as we omit the ip_restrictions {} block from Terraform configuration, these changes will not revert.

Comment: Could you point me to any whitepaper documentation about this behavior? I am in the process of making big decisions based on this behavior and I want to make sure we are not accidently using a "bug feature" if you know what I mean.

Comment: There is some documented restriction with azurerm_app_service 
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service 
`User has to explicitly set scm_ip_restriction to empty slice ([]) to remove it.`

Comment: So, why isn't this specified for the app_settings{} block? If I omit app_settings from the Terraform configuration, and then go into the Azure Portal and add various key:value pairs and run terraform apply, there are no detected changes and the application settings are not reverted.